# New VS Azure Function project targeting .Net Standard 2.0 fails with InternalServerError

Tags: .net-core, visual-studio-2017, asp.net-core-2.0, azure-functions, azure-functions-core-tools

I'm using Visual Studio 15.7.6 and Azure Functions V2 and Web Job Tools 15.0.40617.0 with .Net Core SDK 2.1.302 installed on my dev machine.

I can create a new Azure Function project, target .Net Standard 2.0 and run it locally fine. However, when I deploy it to Azure and execute it returns 500 InternalServerError.

The Visual Studio template produces the following templated code:

```
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace FunctionApp1
{
    public static class Function1
    {
        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public static IActionResult Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post", Route = null)]HttpRequest req, TraceWriter log)
        {
            log.Info("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

            string name = req.Query["name"];

            string requestBody = new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEnd();
            dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(requestBody);
            name = name ?? data?.name;

            return name != null
                ? (ActionResult)new OkObjectResult($"Hello, {name}")
                : new BadRequestObjectResult("Please pass a name on the query string or in the request body");
        }
    }
}
```

Is the Visual Studio out of sync with the tool chain versions?

I noticed that if I create a function online using C# script (CSX) the following method works, but I have no idea what version of functions it uses:

```
using System.Net;
using System.Web;

public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run(HttpRequestMessage req, TraceWriter log)
{
    return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "Hello world!");
}
```

If I add Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc and try to use IActionResults it won't compile.

I'm guessing there's some compatibility issue I'm missing?

Is there a sample Visual Studio project using Functions V2 and .Net Standard that works in the local and Azure runtimes?

-John

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wait, I think I may have just figured it out. Looks like a new Azure Function defaults to the v1 runtime (understandable). If I change this to "beta" it worked.

[image]

I wanted to post this to save others the time I spent on this.

Am I interpreting this correctly?

-John

Comment: Yes, v1 is is Full Framework, beta is v2 is .NET Standard

Comment: Thanks @Mikhail. I feel like I missed some basic public documentation somewhere that mentioned that, would you have a pointer?

Comment: Actually, going back now and looking that setting isn't even there any longer - now what?